# How to find changelists submitted in the last week for a particular user using Perforce?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to ask Perforce to list all changelists submitted by a particular user in a specific time frame ?

**p4 changes @2001/04/01,@now** 
This lists all the changes submitted from 1st April till now.

**p4 changes -m 5 -u edk**
Shows the last five submitted changelists from user edk.

Is there a way to combine both the above for a particular directory ?

Comment: Actually, neither of these command lines restricts to submitted changelists. That is, you can get pending changelists as well with those commands. To restrict to submitted changelists add `-s submitted`.

Comment: @Laurence-Gonsalves Yes forgot to add -s submitted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can combine them like so:

**p4 changes -m 5 -u edk -s submitted @2001/04/01,@now**

To specify a directory:

**p4 changes -m 5 -u edk -s submitted //depot/path/to/directory/...@2001/04/01,@now**

Comment: Would there also be a way to find out if a particular changelist has been integrated to another branch as well ?

Comment: From the documentation:

The -i flag also includes any changelists integrated into the
specified files.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using bash, you can script the whole command:

```
p4 changes -l -i -m 50 -u $USERNAME -s submitted @`date --date="1 week ago" +"%Y/%m/%d"`,@now
```

(I'm also using `-l` to include the full commit message.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get changes in a particular time frame,

Example : p4 changes -u abc -s submitted @2015/09/01:12:02:49,2015/10/01:11:20:55

This should list the submitted changes of 'abc' in the give time frame, that is from : 2015/09/01 12:02:49 to  2015/10/01 11:20:55. Note the ':' which concatenates the date and time.