# command change with perforce

Tags: c#, perforce, p4api.net

in order to get list of change in specific period we use the command change

```
p4 changes @2001/04/01,@now
```

i am using the p4api.net to get this list of changes so i have to use :

```
 P4Command cm1 = new P4Command(ps, "changes", true, String.Format("{0}", deppath1));
```

but the problem how can i specify the two options , i tried that and its not working 
please help me, 
for more help  understand what i am looking for
[How to find changelists submitted in the last week for a particular user using Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911739/how-to-find-changelists-submitted-in-the-last-week-for-a-particular-user-using-p?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: You need `Repository.GetChangelists` (http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Repository_GetChangelists.htm)

Comment: no that's not what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the p4 changes doesn't work in this case when we use p4api.net :

```
p4 changes file.c@2010/05/01,2010/06/01
```

miss a blank between file.c and @ so cm1.addArg is not working in this case because it add a space and it will not be executed